# Prevent script file to invoke remotely using SSH

Tags: ssh

I am trying to prevent a script from being invoked remotely. User need to SSH login instead first and then run the script

`ssh remote-server "script.sh"` should fail

`ssh remote-server` and after login
`./script.sh` should work

I can change the ownership and apply `chmod`, but then the remote user can use `ssh remote-server "sudo -u newuser ./script.sh"`

Using AWS EC2 instance

Answer (score 2):

Running `ssh foo@remote-server` followed by `./script.sh` is equivalent to running `ssh foo@remote-server ./script.sh`, and running `ssh foo@remote-server` followed by `sudo -u bar ./script.sh` is equivalent to `ssh foo@remote-server sudo -u bar ./script.sh` (except `sudo` might fail because it needs a TTY, which can be worked around easily). So I'm afraid what you are asking does not make sense. Anything you do to work around this artificial difference, such as testing for the presence of `$TERM` or `[ -t 0 ]` are probably easily worked around.

Comment: In addition to non-TTY-ness, trivially fixed by `ssh -t[t]`, there are minor differences running under a login shell and being exec'ed from a noninteractive one -- enough so I've seen plenty of Qs from people with the reverse problem: a script they _want_ to invoke remotely breaks. But I concur these are minor enough a competent user who wants to _can_ work around them.